# Comparative advantages between C vs C++ for new projects

Tags: c++, c, linux, comparison

For each new low-level program or library I write on POSIX systems, I always have to start out with the initial decision: *do I write it in vanilla C, or do I go with C++?* I like to think that each time I'm making a relatively informed decision, but I wonder if there's something I'm missing.

This isn't a *which is better* question, but rather, *what aspects of each are better*? Presumably, each has compelling strengths. In which cases should I chose the one instead of the other?

For example, below are some of the points I consider. **What else am I missing?**

### Favoring C

- **Compatibility**: Virtually every language and framework has some mechanism for interfacing with code written in C.
- **Simplicity**: Debugging template code makes you age faster
- **Popularity**: Think of all your favorite applications, servers, interpreters, and other tools. Chances are most of them are written in C, even though C++ was available when they started. All the cool kids use C.

### Favoring C++

- **The STL**: You certainly *could* implement your own RB-tree, quicksort algorithm, or double-linked list. But it probably won't be as good.
- **Templates**: Sure, it's a pre-processor function masquerading as a language feature, but it sure is convenient.
- **Classes**: C++ isn't exactly smalltalk, but at least it's not fancy assembly language either.
- **Compatibility**: You can still use C in a C++ project.

Comment: If you wanna be a cool kid, I guess you've already answered your question...

Comment: How about expressiveness in C++? And automation of resource management? And exceptions? Con: it's a more complex language. In any case, you should just use which language you can express your ideas in the best, according to your capability in the language.

Comment: "But it probably won't be as good." isn't the reason; it should say "But you don't have to."

Comment: Templates are *much* more than a glorified preprocessor, especially when compared to cpp.

Comment: To those of you who voted to close this question, I'd just like to say: "you've got to be bloody kidding." I spent 15 minutes searching for this information on S.O. before asking, *certain* that someone would have asked it before by now. And I was extremely careful to make sure that the question was clear, concise and non-argumentative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ simply has many more features than C. That makes it a more complex language. But the benefit of using these features is that you will have to write (and maintian) less code.

You're not required to use templates, stl, exceptions, function overloads, or whatever C++ feature. But if your problem needs *just one* of these features, your program will be more readable if you do it in C++, rather than emulating the missing functionality in C.

Answer (score 8):

I think you're making it more complicated than it really is. Which language are you better at in expressing your idea? If neither, and if you're a beginner at both, use C; otherwise if you're good at both pick what you feel like. Otherwise it doesn't matter nearly as much as just starting.

> **Alice**: Would you tell me, please, which way I ought to go from here?
>
> **The Cat**: That depends a good deal on where you want to get to
>
> **Alice**: I don't much care where.
>
> **The Cat**: Then it doesn't much matter which way you go.
>
> **Alice**: so long as I get somewhere.
>
> **The Cat**: Oh, you're sure to do that, if only you walk long enough.

Comment: The point is, having multiple options, what features of each option might influence the decision as to which language to use?

Comment: It boils down to this: C is simple. That's a very good thing. C++ offers advanced abstraction tools. That's a very good thing as well. Then there's what you're comfortable with. That's roughly what it boils down to.

Comment: @tylerl: If you have no criteria to evaluate the features of each, "it doesn't much matter which way you go."  If you *could* make the C vs C++ decision in a vacuum, then it would have been decided long ago and one language would no longer be used.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to mention that in C++ there are destructors that are called automatically, so when used correctly (RAII) you don't need to worry about resource deallocation. Another good feature are exceptions that could make the error handling easier and more maintainable.

Comment: This is crucial as projects get bigger. The amount of segmentation faults and core dumps from manual memory management in C (pointers) can be minimized greatly with C++ STL allocators following RAII.

Answer (score 2):

For myself, there is only two reasons to use C. First is if you need the code to be extremely portable (going to be used as a library in different languages and/or operating systems), and second if you need raw speed, which usually isn't a big deal as C++ typically performs only slightly slower than c (not including OO features).

I really enjoy the OO features of C++, which if used properly can make life a lot easier when developing applications.

Comment: C++ doesn't perform slower than C.

Comment: Idiomatic C++ typically performs faster, because template code can be specialized. And of course, anything you can do in C you can do in C++, and perhaps more expressively too, so any C program can be "converted" to C++. Of course, it's implementations we're comparing, not languages; languages don't have a speed.

Comment: GMan, that is not technically true. Even "turing complete" languages can be structured in different ways. The reason I don't see a real speed difference between C and C++ is because they're so similar.

Comment: If you do some benchmarking between equivelant c and c++ programs you will find that c programs have a slightly faster startup time, and typically a slightly faster run time. It is usally faster by 1-5%, which, as I said, is only important if you need raw speed.

Comment: @regality show me the tests. make sure there are no io in them or else use stdio for both, because we already know that the iostreams are slower than the stdio.

Comment: It will vary between compiler and system, and due to complexity and the amount of homework I have right now, I don't feel like putting on a large example. To test startup time I compiled the program main(){} with gcc and g++ and the c version consistently ran in 0.002-0.003 seconds, while the c++ version stayed in the range of 0.004-0.006. Anyone experienced programmer knows that 99.99% of the time this is not enough to waste your time thinking about. It only matters if you are forking a process thousands of times a second or something to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you favor C over C++. I do too. However, ease of use is the most important factor in programming. C++ has better string support and more libraries, so for non-trivial projects, such as database access and stuff like that, go with C++. If you are aiming to be cross platform and maybe want to work on a lower level, use C. Besides, they're both the same anyway.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is better in almost every way: safer, more efficient, works better in large projects... The only exception is that you can't use it when you interface with other languages. But in that case you still use C++ and add a small C layer for the interfacing part.

Comment: I might be a little rusty here, but doesn't **extern "C"** give the code C linkage?  (And isn't that what most/all other languages require for interfacing?)  Sorry, I haven't had to do this for a while, so I don't recall the specifics.  But I don't recall having to write a C "shim" in cases like this.

Comment: That's what I meant with a "C layer": you can't have an object-oriented interface for the interfacing part.

Answer (score 0):

C has some advantages above C++ in the early phase of a project, it's simpler, easier and requires less design decisions. *However*, as the project grows so do the advantages of C++ and Object Oriented Code, which are essentially: Encapsulation, Abstraction and Information Hiding. The drawback is usually slightly slower code unless you break encapsulation.

Yes, it's possible to write like C++ in C, too, but it is far more complex and a hell to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

When I have a choice, I go with a subset of C++.

- **compatibility** - not a problem, you can use extern "C" for linking with C libraries
- **simplicity** - avoid templates, overloading operators, and other C++ feature that obfuscate code

You still get the advantages of classes and RAII.